# Toggle boolean value of subdocuments

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i am trying to toggle the boolean value inside an array which is a collection of objects, problem is that field is being triggered for two both objects inside array, and i want to toggle it for a one object only.

**Document:**

```
"Invitation" : [ 
    {
        "__v" : 0,
        "ID" : ObjectId("54afaabd88694dc019d3b628"),
        "__t" : "USER",
        "_id" : ObjectId("54b5022b583973580c706784"),
        "Accepted" : false
    }, 
    {
        "__v" : 0,
        "ID" : ObjectId("54af6ce091324fd00f97a15f"),
        "__t" : "USER",
        "_id" : ObjectId("54bde39cdd55dd9016271f14"),
        "Accepted" : false
    }
]
```

**Controller:**

```
User.find({_id: req.user._id},'Invitation',function(err,docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
        var results = [];

        async.each(docs,function(doc,callback) {

            async.each(doc.Invitation,function(invite,callback) {
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {'_id': doc._id, 'Invitation._id': invite._id},
                    {'$set': {'Invitation.$.Accepted': !invite.Accepted}},
                    function(err,doc) {
                        results.push(doc);
                        callback(err);
                    }
                );
            },callback);
        },function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);

            console.log('end'+results);
        });

});
```

**MORE:**

ID field inside Invitation array is objectId of person, let's say **Bob** and **David** send Invitations, so there are two objects inside Invitation array, that means i have two Invitations from two different person, i.e ( Bob and David) now i want to accept invitation of Bob only, so when i accept invitation of Bob, Accepted field should be triggered as **true** of Bob object in database, now the results that are shown in below answer have both objects set to **true**, where i only want accepted invitation to be true.

Same is happening with me when i accept invitation of only one user/person both objects are getting true.

Comment: Yes it's me again. So the point that is coming out of this question is "one time only". Can you make it clear why this would be required of a "toggle" and what the expected result would be. As always "edit your question" rather than post in responses. Just alert. As it reads, the code will update each element of the array in separate statements and change the boolean value to the reverse of what it is. I should know, since I wrote it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the result that you claim, which means it works for me and the rest of the world. Here is the abridged listing as a single script example:

```
    var async = require('async'),
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    var invitationSchema = new Schema({
      "ID": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId },
      "Accepted": Boolean
    });

    var userSchema = new Schema({
      "Invitation": [invitationSchema]
    });


    var User = mongoose.model( 'User', userSchema );

    User.find({},'Invitation',function(err,docs) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var results = [];

      async.each(docs,function(doc,callback) {
        async.each(doc.Invitation, function(invite,callback) {
          User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "_id": doc._id, "Invitation._id": invite._id },
            { "$set": { "Invitation.$.Accepted": !invite.Accepted } },
            function(err,doc) {
              results.push(doc);
              callback(err);
            }
          );
        },callback);
      },function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log( results.slice(-1)[0] );
        process.exit();
      });
    });
```

So that clearly "toggles" both values as requested and works perfectly.

This is the result from me on one shot:

```
{ _id: 54be2f3360c191cf9edd7236,
  Invitation:
   [ { __v: 0,
       ID: 54afaabd88694dc019d3b628,
       __t: 'USER',
       _id: 54b5022b583973580c706784,
       Accepted: true },
     { __v: 0,
       ID: 54af6ce091324fd00f97a15f,
       __t: 'USER',
       _id: 54bde39cdd55dd9016271f14,
       Accepted: true } ] }
```

Comment: i want to toggle only one value not both, objects inside Invitation are from different persons, so when i accept invitation of a particular person only his document should be accepted, why would i want both documents true.

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat Needs a cleaner and clearer explanation from you. Based on what you have said to date, this works as designed and "toggles  the present values". I already asked you (three times now including your previous question) to clearly explain what you expect and why it should be so. Your present examples do not show that.

Comment: @Neilunn Edited with More, please have a look

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat I just want to point out that editing your original question and changing the content is considered to be "very rude and uncool on this site" You ask a question and you get the answer to the question you asked. Not others fault that you asked the wrong question. Now, me being "very cool and a super nice guy here". Presumably **"Bob"** is only a single element in the presented array. It's really just a matter of restricting the query to just include that single item as a match. Is this really what you still have no idea how to do?

Comment: @NeilLunn--edited question as you said, presume that there two or more objects inside Invitation, how would i restrict query for single element then. –

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat You have asked a completely different question to what you originally asked. Now what do you think is "cool" here. That I waste my time submitting what I already have and having this long conversation with you just to explain how you are doing this all wrong and changing my answer several times just to suit you? Or accepting the help you have been given to arrive at this as "helpful" and rewarding people to then come to another succinct question you really wanted to ask? This is a Q&A base and not a forum or chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69205/discussion-between-shailesh-shekhawat-and-neil-lunn).

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat I'm not doing any more chats with you. You need to read back and understand. You cannot keep changing questions like this. You ask **one** question and you get **one** answer. Anything else you submit another question. Submit question / Answered / Accept / Move on., Keep to the pattern or people will see you do not and will not help you.

Comment: @NeilLunn-please upvote this question as i have been blocked from asking more questions.:( and sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat Not surprised. And do you think your behavior warrants anything else? I was quite clear. **Ask one question only**. You do not get to change it when you think you have "another" problem. The answer solved the question you asked, so you accept it and move on. If you did not ask the "right" question then that was your fault and not the person who answered. Accept/Retract, then post another question as a comment. Post the same question again as a "duplicate"? This is not how to behave here. Do the right thing when your block is removed.

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat Not my downvote. I'm clearly not the only person aware of your actions here.